# Set template from override controller with Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, templates, prestashop-1.7

I overrieded a controller in Prestashop 1.7 like this :

**/override/controllers/front/MyAccountController.php**

```
    class MyAccountController extends MyAccountControllerCore
    {


    /**
     * Assign template vars related to page content
     * @see FrontController::initContent()
     */
    public function initContent()
    {
        $this->context->smarty->assign([
            'logout_url' => $this->context->link->getPageLink('index', true, null, 'mylogout')
        ]);

        parent::initContent();
        $this->setTemplate("module:configurateur/views/templates/front/my-account.tpl");
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to call a view in my custom module "configurateur" with this line :

```
 $this->setTemplate("module:configurateur/views/templates/front/my-account.tpl");
```

This file exists and is in the right folder (I think) :

**\modules\configurateur\views\templates\front\my-account.tpl**

When I try to load the page, I have this error :

> No template found for **module:configurateur/views/templates/front/my-account.tpl**
>   at line 68 in file classes/Smarty/TemplateFinder.php

Can anyone tell my what's wrong please ?

Answer (score 1):

The syntax "module:..." is [only for ModuleFrontController objects](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/3ced84daf906bd4c5924b48948fc75f567fc025a/classes/controller/ModuleFrontController.php#L58), not for FrontController :

In your case your should use the hook [DisplayOverrideTemplate](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/3ced84daf906bd4c5924b48948fc75f567fc025a/classes/controller/FrontController.php#L1375) or redirect the page myaccount to a module controller.